# ValueError with scikit-learn PLSRegression when used in Pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to use scikit-learns PLSRegressor class as an intermediate step for dimensionality reduction but am receiving the following error.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (100)
```

It is my understanding from the scikit-learn docs that any intermediate step in a Pipeline that implements fit and transform should work. The PLSRegression class does implement these methods.

> class sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline(steps)
>
> Sequentially apply a list of transforms and a final estimator. 
>   Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they must implement fit and transform methods. The final estimator only needs to implement fit.

Below is an example that demonstrates the behavior. Am I doing something wrong or missing something obvious?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDy'))

pipeline = make_pipeline(PLSRegression(n_components=2), LinearRegression())

X = df.ix[:, :-1]
y = df['y']

pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Here is the full trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pls.py", line 15, in <module>
    pipeline.fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 270, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 512, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (100)
```

I understand the error, but since this is part of a pipeline I do not have any control of the shape of the array once it enters the pipeline. I have tried many different iterations of reshaping `X.values` before fitting, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: It seems this module is in [quite a bad shape](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4122).

Comment: @sascha Thanks for pointing me to this. There is even a mention of it not working in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that in most of the scikit classes for dimensionality reduction, `transform` method doesn't take Y as parameter and return transformed X. In case of PLS it returns "x_scores if Y is not given, (x_scores, y_scores) otherwise" (cited from documentation)

In order to make it work with pipeline you can just create a simple wrapper:

```
class PLSRegressionWrapper(PLSRegression):

    def transform(self, X):
        return super().transform(X)

    def fit_transform(self, X, Y):
        return self.fit(X,Y).transform(X)
```

Tested with Python3.6